# Flatten array within array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geojson

I'm getting data from a geojson file and I want to flatten an array within an array to be able to show this data within a material table.

I have the following code:

```
          const geoListData: Array<any> = [];
          const features = geoData.features; // feature array
          const latIdx = 0;
          const lonIdx = 1;

          // iterate over each feature
          features.forEach((feature: any) => {
            const geoListArray: any = [];

            // build up GeoListEntry
            const geoListEntry: GeoListEntry = {
              name: feature.properties.name,
              category: feature.properties.category,
              lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[latIdx],
              lon: feature.geometry.coordinates[lonIdx],
              prio: feature.properties.prio
            };

            geoListArray.push(geoListEntry);

            // get values from geojson
            feature.properties.values.forEach((element: any) => {
              const valuesEntry: any = {
                [element.name]: element.value
              };
              geoListArray.push(valuesEntry);
            });

            this.logger.debug(`geoListArray: ${JSON.stringify(geoListArray)}`);

            geoListData.push(geoListArray);
          });

      return geoListData;
    }));
```

My logger output looks like that:

```
[{"name":"90","category":"Arc 12 month","lat":7.613333333,"lon":47.555555,"prio":0},{"bearing":12345},{"intensity_mean":0},{"intensity_min":0},{"intensity_max":0}]
```

But I want something like that:

```
[{"name":"90","category":"Arc 12 month","lat":7.613333333,"lon":47.555555,"prio":0,"bearing":12345,"intensity_mean":0,"intensity_min":0,"intensity_max":0}]
```

I'm close, but I can't find the solution.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: That's not an array within an array - it's a series of objects within an array. And you want to combine them into a single object inside an array.

Comment: Can you post your initial data?

Comment: After @VLAZ clarification you should [edit] the question and make it clearer, specify what you really want since the desired output doesn't match the description of what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pushing it to `array`, add property directly to the `object`

```
// iterate over each feature
features.forEach((feature: any) => {
  const geoListArray: any = [];

  // build up GeoListEntry
  const geoListEntry: GeoListEntry = {
    name: feature.properties.name,
    category: feature.properties.category,
    lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[latIdx],
    lon: feature.geometry.coordinates[lonIdx],
    prio: feature.properties.prio
  };

  // get values from geojson
  feature.properties.values.forEach((element: any) => {
    geoListEntry[element.name] = element.value
  });

  geoListArray.push(geoListEntry);

  this.logger.debug(`geoListArray: ${JSON.stringify(geoListArray)}`);

  geoListData.push(geoListArray);
});
```